# How to save a data with comma in character varying that passes through a trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have a field of type character varying but I get an error when trying to save a data that contains decimal. I want to save that data without problem.

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "public.usuarios_trigger_process_audit"


BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON usuarios

FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_audit();
```

---

This the PROCEDURE:

```
DECLARE
    newtable text;
    col information_schema.columns %ROWTYPE;
    txtquery text;
    line_old TEXT;
    tmpquery text;
    i int;
    columns_old text[];
BEGIN
    IF ( TG_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' ) THEN
    SELECT TG_TABLE_NAME || '_actividad' INTO newtable;    /*  select TG_RELNAME || '_actividad' into newtable; */
    ELSE
    SELECT TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '_' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_actividad' INTO newtable;    /*  select TG_RELNAME || '_actividad' into newtable; */
    END IF;

    PERFORM creartablaactividad( TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME );

    IF ( TG_OP = 'DELETE' ) THEN
    line_old := TRIM( substr(OLD::text,2,(select length(OLD::text)-2)) );
    columns_old := STRING_TO_ARRAY( line_old, ',' );
    i := 0;
    tmpquery := '''' || array_to_string(columns_old, ''',''') || '''';
    tmpquery := replace(tmpquery,','''',',',NULL,');
        /* SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, inet_client_addr(), now (), ''D'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery; */
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, now (), ''D'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery;
        EXECUTE txtquery;
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSIF ( TG_OP = 'UPDATE' ) THEN
    line_old := TRIM( substr(OLD::text,2,(select length(OLD::text)-2)) );
        columns_old := STRING_TO_ARRAY( line_old, ',' );
        i := 0;
        tmpquery := '''' || array_to_string(columns_old, ''',''') || '''';
        tmpquery := replace(tmpquery,','''',',',NULL,');
        tmpquery := replace(tmpquery,','''',',',NULL,');
        /* SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, inet_client_addr(), now (), ''ANT'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery; */
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, now (), ''ANT'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery;
        EXECUTE txtquery;
        line_old := TRIM( substr(NEW::text,2,(select length(NEW::text)-2)) );
        columns_old := STRING_TO_ARRAY( line_old, ',' );
        i := 0;
        tmpquery := '''' || array_to_string(columns_old, ''',''') || '''';
        tmpquery := replace(tmpquery,','''',',',NULL,');
        /* SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, inet_client_addr(), now (), ''U'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery; */
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, now (), ''U'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery;
        EXECUTE txtquery;
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF ( TG_OP = 'INSERT' ) THEN
    line_old := TRIM( substr(NEW::text,2,(select length(NEW::text)-2)) );
        columns_old := STRING_TO_ARRAY( line_old, ',' );
        i := 0;
        tmpquery := '''' || array_to_string(columns_old, ''',''') || '''';
        tmpquery := replace(tmpquery,','''',',',NULL,');
        /* SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, inet_client_addr(), now (), ''I'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery; */
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO actividad.' || newtable ||' SELECT user, now (), ''I'',' || replace(tmpquery, ',''''',',NULL') into txtquery;
        EXECUTE txtquery;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END;
```

---

My table usuarios:

[image]

The error:

[image]

Comment: You need to show some examples.  For instance, what does your code look like?  There is no problem with having commas in character strings.

Comment: What happens is that when you save a record that record goes through a trigger to save a copy. There is the problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show us the exact SQL you're running, and any triggers, and the exact error you're getting? Then we can better answer your question.

Comment: I already updated the question.

Comment: the error looks pretty clear - you try smth like `insert into t(c1,c2) select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5` number of returned columns is bigger then number of destination columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format()` to make creating a dynamic SQL query much easier as it will automatically deal with identifiers and literals correctly. One thing that people usually overlook is that you can expand a single record expression to all its columns using `(...).*` - this also works for `NEW` and `OLD` record variables in a trigger, e.g. `select (new).*`

You can also pass variables to a dynamic SQL with the [`using`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) keyword of the `execute` statement. There is no need to convert the record back and forth between a record and a text representation.

Using that possibility your trigger function can be simplified to:

```
DECLARE 
  l_sql text;
BEGIN
    IF TG_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' THEN
      newtable := TG_TABLE_NAME || '_actividad';
    ELSE
      newtable := TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '_' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_actividad';
    END IF;

    PERFORM creartablaactividad(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME);
    l_sql := 'INSERT INTO actividad.%I  SELECT current_user, current_timestamp, %L, ($1).*';

    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      execute format(l_sql, newtable, 'D') using OLD;
      RETURN OLD;
    ELSE
      -- covers UPDATE and INSERT
      execute format(l_sql, newtable, 'U') using NEW;
      RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END;
```

Using placeholders like `%I` and `%L` also makes it possible to define the actual SQL only once and re-use it. Those "parameters" are replaced by the `format()` function (which preserves the `$1`)

Note the use of `($1).*` inside the SQL string. That will make the `execute` statement expand the record parameter `$1` to all its columns. The record itself is passed "natively" with the `USING` keyword.

---

The use of `INSERT` without a target column list (`insert into some_table ...` instead of `insert into some_table (col1, col2, ...) ...`) is a pretty fragile thing to do. If the source and the target don't match the insert can fail quite easily. .

---

If you don't run massive reporting on the audit tables (where having explicit column names would be much more efficient) you might want to think of a more generic audit trigger using a `JSON` or `HSTORE` column to store the whole record. There are several ready-made audit triggers available:

- http://okbob.blogspot.de/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html
- https://github.com/wingspan/wingspan-auditing
- https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus